# swift conditionally call unwind segue using shouldPerformSegue

Tags: ios, arrays, validation, swift3, unwind-segue

I have two view controllers: Step3VC (we'll call this 'A') and Step3AddJobVC (we'll call this 'B'). I'm trying to validate some data on 'B' before performing an unwind segue back to 'A'.

'B' takes some user input, and I want to verify that the user input is not duplicate. The user is making a list of chores, and so duplicate names won't work. When the user taps 'save', the unwind segue performs, and the data is added to an array.

Here's the problem: the array is on 'A', but the validation needs to happen on 'B' before 'A' gets called. How do I do that?

**What I've tried:**

I've tried using `shouldPerformSegue` in 'B', but the array comes back blank `[]`. So that's no good. Here's the code from 'B':

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    print("identifier is: ", (identifier))
    print("sender is: ", (sender)!)
    let newVC = Step3VC()
    print(newVC.dailyJobs)
    return false
}
```

So then I tried putting the validation into 'A' during the unwind segue...

```
@IBAction func unwindToStep3VC(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let sourceVC = sender.source as! Step3AddJobVC
    let updatedJob = sourceVC.job

    // check for duplicate names
    for name in dailyJobs {
        print(name.name)
        if name.name.lowercased() == (sourceVC.jobTextField.text?.lowercased()) {        // check to see if lowercased text matches
            print("error")
            // call alert function from sourceVC
            sourceVC.duplicateNameCheck()
            return
        }
    }
    if let selectedIndexPathSection = jobsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.section {      // if tableview cell was selected to begin with

        // Update existing job
        if selectedIndexPathSection == 0 {
            let selectedIndexPathRow = jobsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            dailyJobs[(selectedIndexPathRow?.row)!] = updatedJob!
            jobsTableView.reloadData()
        } else if selectedIndexPathSection == 1 {
            let selectedIndexPathRow = jobsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            weeklyJobs[(selectedIndexPathRow?.row)!] = updatedJob!
            jobsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    } else {

        // Add a new daily job in the daily jobs array
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: dailyJobs.count, section: 0)
        dailyJobs.append(updatedJob!)
        jobsTableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

...but it gave the error:

```
popToViewController:transition: called on <ToDo_App.SetupNavController 0x7fcfd4072c00> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.
```

If I pull out the 'if' validation code, the unwind segue works properly. The data is transferred and does the right thing. The problem is that if the user enters duplicate entries, I can't figure out how to stop them.

This is my code for checking if user input is duplicate:

```
// check for duplicate names
    for name in dailyJobs {
        print(name.name)
        if name.name.lowercased() == (sourceVC.jobTextField.text?.lowercased()) {        // check to see if lowercased text matches
            print("error")
            // call alert function from sourceVC
            sourceVC.duplicateNameCheck()
            return
        }
    }
```

What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this? How do I call the variables from 'A' while I'm in 'B' to perform my validation BEFORE the unwind segue is called / performed?

Comment: Your first approach is right, but when you say `let newVC = Step3VC()` you are creating a new instance of `Step3VC` so it has an empty array.  Either pass a reference to your existing `Step3VC` to "B" when you perform that validation, or implement a delegation pattern between B and A so that B can ask A if the new value is acceptable

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11! Can you give some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to validate the things in shouldPerformSegue which is the right place, the thing which you are doing wrong is recreating new object of Step3VC and trying to access dailyJobs which is never set with value.

```
let newVC = Step3VC()
print(newVC.dailyJobs)
```

What you have do is pass dailyJobs form VC A to VC B while presenting VC B and then check if the data is duplicate or not in shouldPerformSegue.

Your code have to look like:

```
class VCA: UIViewController {
  var dailyJobs = getDailyJobsFromServer()


  @IBAction segueToVCB(sender: UIButton) {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vcB = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCB") as! VCB
    vcB.dailyJobs = dailyJobs
    self.present(vcB, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

}

class VCB: UIViewController {
  var dailyJobs: //DataType

  override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    //Here you do comparision with dailyJobs
    if dailyJobs == userInput {

    }
    return false
  }

}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't think to send over the variable from vcA to vcB. I was just trying to figure out how to get the data from B back to A once it was validated. Thanks! I'm still working on finalizing the code, but your answer was the tip I needed to move forward.